# Multimedia PDF (Audio, Video and Links) That works on Desktop and iOS

Tags: video, audio, pdf, url, ios

We've got a client that wants to have a PDF that has embedded audio, video and links.

Using Acrobat Pro 9.x I've been able to embed all three no problem. They all work/playback if I use Acrobat Pro/Acrobat Reader. But don't show up in OS X's Preview at all. They also don't show up in iOS. Links work everywhere, but no multimedia.

So I tried creating a similar document via Apple's iBooks Author, then exported as a PDF. Links work, but multimedia doesn't seem to work anywhere.

Is there any way to make a PDF that works universally with embedded links and multimedia?

Answer (score 1):

Multimedia objects inside a PDF file is not something universally supported. It will work with Adobe's Readers but I have not seen it work in any other third party reader. It might be a better option for you to create a Flash-based application with your multimedia files embedded and distribute that instead.

As @Ramhound mentioned in his comments, you could also install Adobe Reader in all the targeted devices.

Comment: Yeah, this has been my experience. The problem is they want iOS support as well. Looking like I may be dealing with a two file solution: one created from iBooks Author, and the other from Acrobat Pro.

Comment: Flash is not supported on iOS

Comment: @Keefer - The solution would be to install Adobe Acrobat on the OS X and iOS device.  Adobe adds lots of features that not everyone supports to the PDF standard.

Comment: I agree with @Ramhound about his solution. However I must say that [flash is indeed supported in iOS](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/logged_in/abansod_iphone.html)